# How to use the DOM history object correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, browser-history

According to this page on the Mozilla Developer Network, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history, doing `window.history.back()` ....

> ... will act exactly like the user clicked on the Back button in their
>   browser toolbar

But that's not what I am finding.

I have pages 1, 2, 3 and 4, with custom back buttons on the last three.

If I click from 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4, then use the browser's back button, I will go from 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1.

If I do the same with my custom back buttons, however, when I tried to back track it will go 4 -> 3 -> 4 -> 3 -> 4 -> ...etc

Is there a way around this?

Here's my code:

```
<button onclick="window.history.back()" id="back-btn" class="button left ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> Back</span></button>
```

(You'll see that I am styling it with jQuery...)

Comment: Interesting. Do you have anything that's working with the pop/pushstate functionality of the history API?

Comment: Ohgodwhy, not unless jQuery is doing something funny in the background, but I doubt it...

Comment: Are you using jQuery mobile or just jQuery?

Comment: Just jQuery, Ohgodwhy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this out.  Basically I had my button submitting incorrectly.  When I pressed a forward or back button, it appeared to work OK.  When I checked the network interface though (via firebug) I was actually firing off multiple requests in one go.

Now that my buttons are working Ok, the history is also fine!